# How to manipulate async scope in angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this defined in controller
`$scope.files = {};`

Then I have a ajax call to get data and pass to `$scope.files`;

In the same controller. I have a ng-click function which I want to manipulate `$scope.files`
How to do that because it is async. I tried and the $scope.files always return blank `{}`

```
$scope.click = function() {
 //Do something to $scope.files;
}
```

Comment: You're not really showing us enough code to help you. Do you have a fiddle or a plunker you can show?

Comment: Are you calling $scope.click() in the callback of your get request?

Comment: @blesh ok, I will make a plunk later. Its late here.

Comment: @ZackArgyle I call it outside and inside the cb both not work.

Answer (score 2):

My fault. this is not related to async. I can actually get the data.

My problem is the return data is object and I tried to use `.length` to get the length of object so it always return 0 and {}. And I found `.length` for array.

and `Object.keys(a)` for object sizes

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use  [promise/deferred implementation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q). Promises allow you to execute code and once the promise is returned then continue.